# How can I check whether my radio button is checked within ONE div among many others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many div's called "each_item", one behind another.
I am trying to check whether a radio has been checked WITHIN this very div.

My problem is that with my jquery code (see below), all radio buttons of all "each_item" div's are tested. I probably need to use `$(this)`, but I don't know how to use it in the selector I used below ( that is `$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked')`)

```
<div class='each_item'>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='m'>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='f'>

<input type='button' id='btn'>
</div>
```

The jquery i tried is this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    if ($('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').length < 1)
        alert('nothing was checked');
    });
```

Thanks a lot if you could help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to only look within the div.  [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will find the nearest ancestor with that class (the containing div).

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    if ($(this).closest(".each_item").find('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').length < 1)
        alert('nothing was checked');
    });

});
```

Also note that if you have multiple buttons with the same `id`, that is invalid and will likely cause you problems down the line.  `id`s should always be unique.

Answer (score 1):

use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).siblings('input:checked').length < 1) {
        alert('nothing was checked');
    }
});
```

You can remove the `:radio` and `[name=gender]` from your selector because they overdefine what you are actually searching for.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your tip. I removed them and it works for me. Thanks